# UIButton not responding to tap

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

`UIButton` action is not working when I tap. I tried other suggestions from another post on Stack Overflow, but nothing is working. Below is my code:

```
    let saveBtn = GActionBtn(type: .system)

    lazy var footer: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        v.addSubview(saveBtn)
        saveBtn.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        saveBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleSave), for: .touchUpInside)
        saveBtn.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.4470588235, green: 0.6274509804, blue: 0.3960784314, alpha: 1)
        saveBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 27.5
        let attributeString = NSAttributedString(string: "Save".localized(), attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "NunitoSans-Bold", size: 16), NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white])
        saveBtn.setAttributedTitle(attributeString, for: .normal)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            saveBtn.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.centerXAnchor),
            saveBtn.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.centerYAnchor, constant: 54),
            saveBtn.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 312),
            saveBtn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 52)
        ])
        return v
    }()

    @objc private func handleSave() {
        print("save")
    }

    private func setupTableView() {
        tableView = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .grouped)
        tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 80, right: 0)
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        tableView.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive
        tableView.backgroundColor = .white
        tableView.tableFooterView = footer
    }
```

Comment: you should use tableview's default footerView function. and then try to use your button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ferryawijayanto As per `Sh_Khan` suggestion, yes you should return UIButton directly to `tableFooterView`. It will accept it. Try like below,

```
 private func setupTableView() {
    tableView = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .grouped)
    tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 80, right: 0)
    tableView.separatorStyle = .none
    tableView.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive
    tableView.backgroundColor = .white

    let saveBtn = UIButton (type: .system)
    saveBtn.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    saveBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleSave), for: .touchUpInside)
    saveBtn.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.4470588235, green: 0.6274509804, blue: 0.3960784314, alpha: 1)
    saveBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 27.5
    let attributeString = NSAttributedString(string: "Save".localized(), attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "NunitoSans-Bold", size: 16), NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white])
    saveBtn.setAttributedTitle(attributeString, for: .normal)


    tableView.tableFooterView = saveBtn
}
```

If you want to full width and height which is define heightForFooterSection means UIButton automatically update with it's frame from footer's frame. Otherwise you want to custom with static width and height you can use frame without constraint. Of course you should try with constraints too.

I hope it will help to achieve your desired output.

Comment: Have you set heightForFooterInSection frame from UITableViewDataSource? Otherwise If you make frame without constraints like `saveBtn.frame = CGRectFrame` on the declaration part.

Comment: when you mention it I already try since I forgot about that, but it still not showing. I'm not yet try using frame though.

Comment: Hey Good job @ferryawijayanto